# Why I can not read the property of an object passed to a function? In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm getting the next error in function getOlder():
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined*

What's the problem and how to fix it?

```
function person(name, age) {
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age
}

// Returns the older person in a group of persons.
var getOlder = function(people) {
    if (people.length === 0) {
        return new person();
    }

    var older = people[0]; // The first one is the older for now.

    var value;
    for (var _ in people) {
        value = people[_];
        if (value.age > older.age) {
            older = value;
        }
    }
    return older;
};

// Declare some persons.
var paul = new person("Paul", 23);
var jim = new person("Jim", 24);
var sam = new person("Sam", 84);
var rob = new person("Rob", 54);
var karl = new person("Karl", 19);

var older = getOlder(paul, jim);
if (older.name !== "Jim") {
    console.log("Fail");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var getOlder = function() {
    var people = arguments;
    if (people.length === 0) {
        return new person();
    }

    var older = people[0]; // The first one is the older for now.

    var value;
    for (var _ in people) {
        value = people[_];
        if (value.age > older.age) {
            older = value;
        }
    }
    return older;
   };
```

By Accepting no arguments in the function definition and relying on the variable arguments feature of JS you can get away with calling `getOlder(paul, jim)`.

*arguments* is a property of every function which is basically an array of variable arguments provided to it while calling .

Comment: This has an issue; it can not mixed fixed arguments with variable arguments, i.e. function(name, age, emails) being the last one a variable argument.

Comment: true. It takes all the arguments. I thought It fits in your case where you were accepting arguments, all part of a collection.

If you are planning to accept mixed arguments then you will need a array separately and other arguments.

Comment: Anyways in your case it wont make sense to have mixed arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the signature of your function:

```
var getOlder = function(people) {
```

You did not create your function such that it accepts two person objects. You apparently only accept an array, as you're using `people.length` and `people[0]` inside the function. So you also have to pass an array:

```
var older = getOlder([paul, jim]);
```